# cURL Authorization Error - License Manager WooCommerce

Tags: curl, authorization

I'm using [License Manager for WooCommerce](https://www.licensemanager.at/docs/rest-api/developer-documentation/validate-a-license/).
Following the documentation my code looks like this:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.my-url.com/subdir/wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses/validate/".$this->license."?consumer_key=".$this->consumerKey."&consumer_secret=".$this->consumerSecret,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

$result = json_decode($response, true);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $result;
} ?>
```

Calling the URL via a web browser, the result returns a valid json array.
Calling the code via a php file results in a $response with an athorization error.

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

The user exists, has admin rights and even creating new key and secret didn't help.

How can I furhter debug and fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the User-Agent:

**CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']**

```
//validate license key
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.my-url.com/wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses/validate/".$this->lcns."?consumer_key=".$this->lmfwcConsumerKey."&consumer_secret=".$this->lmfwcConsumerSecret,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    $result = json_decode($response, true);

    curl_close($curl);
```